# Go equivalent of decode('hex') in Python

Tags: python, go, encoding

I'm working on converting an existing Python library to Go and am getting hung up on a piece.

Is there a go equivalent to the following Python code?

```
test = "ec033aa702"
test.decode('hex')
```

I've been doing some reading but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri - sorry. That was a bad example. I updated here to actually include something that runs. This example is in Python 2.7; I think Python 3.x changed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/hex"
  "fmt"
  "log"
)

func main() {
  const s = "ec033aa702"
  decoded, err := hex.DecodeString(s)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("%s\n", decoded)
}
```

[DecodeString](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#DecodeString)

[Try it online!](https://play.golang.org/p/Po4sQVPRDc)

Comment: Thanks! I think that's what I was looking for.